# How to get route inside RequestEvent

Tags: routes, event-subscribers

I need to redirect all existing links targeting a few hand-picked nodes to an external domain. I created an EventSubscriber listening to RequestEvents

my.services.yml

```
services:
  my.request_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\my\EventSubscriber\EventSubscriber
    arguments: ['@current_route_match', '@redirect.checker']
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

EventSubscriber.php

```
/* trimmed constructor, etc. for simplicity */

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    // This needs to run before Redirect module
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onKernelRequestCheckRedirect', 34];
    return $events;
  }
  public function onKernelRequestCheckRedirect(RequestEvent $event) {
    // the follwing lines are taken from redirect module 
    // @see https://git.drupalcode.org/project/redirect/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/EventSubscriber/RedirectRequestSubscriber.php#L111
    $request = clone $event->getRequest();
    if (!$this->checker->canRedirect($request)) {
      return;
    }

    /**
     * No matter which route I visit, the $this->routeMatch->getRouteObject is always null,
     * therefore the following lines also don't work as I hoped
     */
    $routeName = $this->routeMatch->getRouteName(); // returns NULL :(
    $nodeId = $this->routeMatch->getParameter('node'); // returns NULL :(

    if ($routeName !== 'entity.node.canonical' || !in_array($nodeId, [MY_HANDPICKED_NODE_IDS]) ) {
      return;
    }
    else {
       // do $event->setResponse(my TrustedRedirectResponse);
    }
}
```

Why is my route object always NULL? How do I get the routing information in my subscriber?

Comment: For debugging/testing purposes, if you try `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();` is it also NULL ?

Comment: Yes, same as injected, all route information is NULL

Comment: Why did you choose the priority 34? Routing is at priority 32. The default priority 0 should work most times unless you need to run before a specific core subscriber.

Comment: @4uk4 Thanks, this was the issue. I was taking a look at the code in the redirect module, they used `34` there and I thought this is good for me too. Simply removing/using the default priority fixed it `$events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onKernelRequestCheckRedirect'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by the priority inside the subscribe function. The redirect module used priority `34` here, but this was not fitting my case. Simply removing/using the default priority in the subscribe function solved the issue.

```
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onKernelRequestCheckRedirect'];
    return $events;
  }
```

This answer is coming from @4uk4's comment below the original question.